# how do I enable keyboard backlight on sony vaio?

Tags: keyboard, backlight

After reading other posts, I think I've found the directory /sys/class/backlight/ but don't know how to edit it to enable the backlight. I'm just getting started with Ubuntu 19.10 with a dual boot set up with Window 7. Help please?

Comment: I think that relates to screen backlight; and as I'm using Lubuntu the command I'd use is `pkexec lxqt-backlight_backend --inc` (or --dec` to decrease it). It has many settings and adjust the internal display brightness for my sony vaoi  (*it makes no difference on external display if connected*); I never played with key lights as they come on when I type (& stay on awhile after I stop typing without me doing anything).

Comment: How can I check the setting of the backlight in the /sys/class/backlight/ directory or do you know which directory the keyboard backlight setting is in?

Comment: My wording wasn't ideal (*I think*); that directory is empty on this workstation which isn't capable of adjusting display brightness, but the directory will contain contents on laptops and boxes where screen brightness is adjustable. I'm not a developer thus the hesitation, but I did testing in 18.10 development cycle (for Lubuntu) on 14 devices and on those 14 the directory related only to screen backlight (not keyboard)

Comment: Try `/sys/devices/platform`. On my old vaio there is a `sony-laptop` directory. There might be something under there. It doesn't have a kb light but my Asus -- which does -- has a setting for the keyboard light in that location.

Comment: Thanks for that. I opened the /sys/devices/platform/ directory and did an ls on it and these are the only things in the directory:alarmtimer          intel_rapl_msr.0   PNP0C14:00     sony-laptop
 coretemp.0          microcode          power          uevent
 eisa.0              pcspkr             reg-dummy      vesa-framebuffer.0
'Fixed MDIO bus.0'   PNP0C0D:00         regulatory.0
 i8042               PNP0C0E:00         serial8250                           I can't find anything that would suggest enabling the keyboard backlight. Any suggestions?

Comment: Within the /sys/devices/platform/sony-laptop/ directory, which other posts suggest the setting for the keyboard backlight is, are only these things: battery_care_health   fanspeed       panel_id          touchpad
battery_care_limiter  lid_resume_S3  power             uevent
driver                lid_resume_S4  subsystem         usb_charge
driver_override       lid_resume_S5  thermal_control
fan_forced            modalias       thermal_profiles
I can't  see anything to suggest where I might enable the keyboard backlight. ...help please.

Comment: On my Asus, the kbd light settings are in a directory under `leds`. Are any of those directory entries directories? Try `find . | grep kbd` or even just `find .` in the `sony-laptop` directory to see a listing of everything under that directory. Also: are you sure your keyboard has a backlight. My Vaio doesn't

Comment: All that's in the sony-laptop directory is this:./uevent
./lid_resume_S5
./panel_id
./fanspeed
./lid_resume_S3
./battery_care_health
./thermal_profiles
./power
./power/runtime_active_time
./power/runtime_active_kids
./power/runtime_usage
./power/runtime_status
./power/autosuspend_delay_ms
./power/async
./power/runtime_suspended_time
./power/runtime_enabled
./power/control
./thermal_control
./usb_charge
./driver
./lid_resume_S4
./driver_override
./subsystem
./touchpad
./fan_forced
./battery_care_limiter
./modalias

Comment: I don't seem to have a directory /leds/

Comment: The keyboard backlight works on Windows 7 but, with black keys, is very difficult to see them at night without the keyboard backlight using Ubuntu.

Comment: What about this: `/etc/modprobe.d/sony-laptop.conf` ? anything?

Comment: Tried that but nothing...not quite sure what it was supposed to do though. I'm a bit of a novice :P